# Flutter increase height and width of Switch?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I creating game with single and two players. for selection i want slide look so i have tried with switch method but its look very small. how to increase height and width of switch? is there any way creating look like this is welcome?

```
    new Center(
      child:
      new Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(50.00),
          child:
        new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Switch(value: _value, onChanged: (bool value1)

            {
              _value=value1;

            },
              materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
              activeThumbImage: new AssetImage("assets/Images/1.png"),
              inactiveThumbImage: new AssetImage("assets/Images/1.png"),

            )
          ],
        )           ,
     ),
    )
```

[image]

Comment: I'm also looking for ways to update the active and inactive images to use a canvas/picuture/image instead of having to use a local asset image or a network image, do you know how?

Comment: Hey Kathir! I think you should mark the answer by diegoveloper as correct, it's very helpful

Answer (score 96):

You could wrap your `Switch` inside a `Transform` widget and change the scale.

```dart
        Transform.scale(scale: 2.0,
                 child: Switch(
                          value: true,
                          onChanged: (bool value1){},
                        ),
                 )
```

Scale = 1 is the default size , 0.5 half size , 2.0 double size, you can play with the values :)

**UPDATE**

Now you can also do it using `SizedBox` + `FittedBox`

```dart
SizedBox(
        width: 150,
        height: 40,
        child: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          child: Switch(
            value: true,
            onChanged: (bool value1) {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Don't forget the `BoxFit.fill` value :)

Comment: The solution is good. I was using `SwitchListTile` and there this solution does magnify the title too and makes the UI weird. Anyways +1 because it solved the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer using a scale will increase both height and width, if you want to control both height and width

Use it like this

```
          SizedBox(
            width: 50,
            height: 30,
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              child: Switch(
                onChanged: (bool value) {
                },
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to CupertinoSwitch, You can copy paste run full code below
You can use `Transform.scale` and set `scale`, 1 means normal size, 0.8 means smaller size

```
Transform.scale(
  scale: 0.8,
  child: CupertinoSwitch(
    value: _switchValue,
    onChanged: (bool value) {
      setState(() {
        switchValue = value;
      });
    },
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrapper your Switch widget inside a SizedBox and set width and height to it.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 80,
  height: 40,
  child: Switch(
    value: isChecked,
    onChanged: (value) {
      //Do you things
    }
  )
)
```

Answer (score -4):

You should put your *switch* inside a container and give it both a height and a width as per your requirement.

Answer (score -5):

You can simply use Container that are more compatible everywhere.

> flutter

```
Container(
                height: //whatever you want
                widget: //whatever you want
                child: Switch(
                    value: true, 
                    onChanged: (){

                }),
              )
```