# Is there a way to increase the height of track in Flutter switch?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make my switch look like this:

But i haven't found a way to increase the size of track. Is there any?

Comment: if you compromise drag behaviour we can make this with stack. including drag behavior will take some extra work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use a [CupertinoSwitch](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSwitch-class.html).

Cupertino switches are the iOS style switches where the track is larger than the node.

Comment: But as i understood, there is no way to change color of the thumb.

Comment: @Zimme you can change `activeColor` and `trackColor` and `thumbColor` in class constructor

Comment: Unfortunately you can only change inactive/active track color with Cupertino switches. However, according to the top answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568958/flutter-increase-height-and-width-of-switch), you can alter the size of the regular Switch by wrapping it in a Transorm.scale widget. The track won't be larger than the node, but you have more color customization options that route.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the height of track we have to use `constraints` and `FittedBox`.

check this

```
Container(
          // color: Colors.cyanAccent,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: 170,
            maxHeight: 170,
            minWidth: 200,
            maxWidth: 200,
          ),
          child: FittedBox(
            child: CupertinoSwitch(
              value: _on,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _on = value;
                });
                print(value);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
```