# How to increase width of Switch in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a Switch like below :
[image]

I tried using `Transform.scale` as parent Widget but it doesn't match with that i want.
How should I increase Switch width? or any other suggestion for create similar(like Toggle or ...)?

Comment: Add your present code

Comment: @OMiShah i didn't write code yet, i just tried transform.scale and switch widget ,  which i realized it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you only can increase size of Switch with `Tranform.scale`, can't increase only width like you want. If you really need that Switch, try use this package [flutter_switch](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_switch) like this :

```
FlutterSwitch(
  width: 300,
  height: 30.0,
  value: true,
  onToggle: (val) {},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SizedBox and FittedBox should do the trick

Same problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568958/flutter-increase-height-and-width-of-switch)